# "Could not find installable ISAM" using OLEDB

Tags: ms-access, oledb

I am trying to connect to an Access database and get the data to CSV but I received the error

> Could not find installable ISAM

This is my connection string:

```
string connectionStringMSAccess = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), @"database\whitelist.mdb") + "';Extended Properties=text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: IIRC when targeting a text file using the OLEDB provider your Data Source is just the folder. Not sure why you are including an `.mdb` file in the connection string (whitelist.mdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `;Extended Properties=text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited` parameters from your connection string. They are not applicable when opening a connection to an .mdb file.